# how to get config list through gRPC in tensorflow serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have served several models through tensorflow server.
I want to know how can I get the whole config list through gRPC in my client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow Serving does not offer an API to fetch the config. It is not recommended to use a running server instance as the source of truth for the config, because (1) it can go down, (2) there can be multiple replicas which could be out of sync, and (3) the read-update-write pattern is race-prone. Instead, the recommended approach is to keep the ground truth config in some persistent store e.g. a database or